# Automating sending excel

Tags: python, excel, email, automation, gmail

I need to send an excel file to an email and repeat that process over 100 times using different excel sheet each on each occurrence.

I initially wrote a Python script that allowed me to have access to my Gmail and automate the process but due to certain constraints, I no longer have access to the Less Secured App option in Google.

I saw that I could use OAuth2.0 but that requires access to Google's API which I also don't have access too.

Is there any other alternative free or paying that would enable me to send these emails automatically at the click of a button?

I'm fairly new to this world but is it safe to assume that regardless of the tool to be used, I will need access to Google's API as I need to access my email first?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you not use an email client (i.e. Outlook) to get you emails. You could then easily do what you need through email client API's

Comment: Unfortunately, I won't be able to use it due to security concerns. I need to use the Gmail account.